# Custom route filters ignoring redirect

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I'm having some trouble trying to create a custom filter. My goal is to make sure specific conditions are met by the authenticated user before allowing them to visit routes defined within the group.

Right now it just continues to /page no problem even though I have confirmed one of those conditions are met. It is ignoring my redirects.

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'registered'), function()
{
    Route::get('/page', array('as' => 'page', 'uses' => 'PageController@getIndex'));
});
```

filters.php

```
Route::filter('registered', function()
{
    if(Auth::check())
    {
        if(!Auth::user()->confirmed())
        {
            return Redirect::route('signup.send.confirmation')->with('alert-warning', 'You must confirm your email address before continuing.  Fill out the form below if you need a new activation email.  Thank you!');
        }

        if(!Auth::user()->registered)
        {
            return Redirect::route('signup.profile')->with('alert-warning', 'You must fill out the following information before continuing.  Thank you!');
        }
    }
});
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your filter. It seems that you allow unregistered users to go to this route. I think what you need is:

```
Route::filter('registered', function()
{
    if(!Auth::check()) {
          return Redirect::route('signup.profile')->with('alert-warning', 'You must fill out the following information before continuing.  Thank you!');
    }

    else
    {
        if(!Auth::user()->confirmed())
        {
            return Redirect::route('signup.send.confirmation')->with('alert-warning', 'You must confirm your email address before continuing.  Fill out the form below if you need a new activation email.  Thank you!');
        }
    }
});
```

If it doesn't solve the issue, you should provide more details, especially how you check those condition are true and if you sure this filter is run.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to explain it but now it is working as it is written in my original post.  I must have overlooked a test somewhere.

Authentication is not needed to access /page.  But if they ARE authenticated, I want to make sure they have completed all the steps necessary to have a completed account/profile.  That is the reasoning for the filter, it does not redirect them if they are not authenticated.

If you are looking to do a custom filter, my original question works! Sorry for wasting anyones time.